# Meaning of vision du monde in Lucien Goldmann's genetic structuralism

Tags: terminology, theory, lucien-goldmann

In the 1960s the French philosopher, sociologist and literary theorist [Lucien Goldmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucien_Goldmann) developed a theory known as "genetic criticism" (e.g. in *Sciences humaines et philosophie. Suivi de structuralisme génétique et création littéraire*, 1966). This theory uses several terms whose meaning is not immediately obvious, e.g. "homology", "vision du monde" and "collective subject".

What is the meaning of "vision du monde" in Goldmann's genetic structuralism?

Comment: This question is split off from an older [question (by another user) that was closed and deleted two years ago](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5843/2191).

Answer (score 1):

Goldmann explains "vision du monde" and how this concept fits into his view on society and literature in the first chapter of *Le Dieu caché*, "Le tout et les parties" ("The whole and the parts"). He cites one of Pascal's [Pensées](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es/%C3%89dition_de_Port-Royal/XXXI) as an example of a turn towards dialectical thinking:

> Donc toutes choses étant causées et causantes, aidées et aidantes, médiatement et immédiatement, et toutes s’entretenant par un lien naturel et insensible qui lie les plus éloignées et les plus différentes, je tiens impossible de connaître les parties sans connaître le tout, non plus que de connaître le tout sans connaître particulièrement les parties.

Translation (from [*Thoughts on Religion and Other Subjects*. Translated from the French. London, 1704](https://archive.org/details/thoughtsonreligix00pasc/page/350/mode/2up), page 350–351):

> All things, then, being in different Regards, Effects and Causes, Dependents and Assistants, near and remote, holding communication with each other by a Natural, tho' imperceptible, Line, which unites the most distant in place, and most repugnant in kind, I see no possibility either of knowing the Parts without the Whole, or of knowing the whole, without a distinct apprehension of the Parts.

Similarly, according to Goldmann, a specific work by a specific author cannot be understood in isolation but needs to be seen as part of the author's entire writings. However, criticism should also look at an author as an individual who is a member of a social group and a social class. The *subjective* meaning that a specific work has for its author does not always coincide with the *objective* meaning that work has for a historian-philosopher. For example, Descartes was religious but cartesian rationalism is atheistic. For this reason, a scholar needs to situate a work in the whole of historical development and social life in order to understand a work's *objective* meaning. (*Le Dieu caché*, pages 15–17)

For a social group, there is a tight correspondence between thought and behaviour. In order for a social group to constitute a social class, two requirements need to be fulfilled: (1) its interests need to be oriented towards a global transformation of social structure and (2) it needs to "express itself on the ideological level by means of a global vision on contemporary man—his qualities, his shortcomings—and by means of an ideal, regarding humanity's future, about what people's relationship should be towards other people and towards the universe" (*Le Dieu caché*, page 26, my translation). Goldmann then goes on to define "vision du monde":

> Une vision du monde, c'est précisément cet ensemble d'aspirations, de sentiments et d'idées qui réunit les membres d'un groupe (le plus souvent, d'une classe sociale) et les oppose aux autres groupes.
> C'est, sans doute, une schématisation, une extrapolation de l'historien, mais l'extrapolation d'une tendance *réelle* chez les membres d'un groupe qui réalisent tous cette conscience de class d'une manière plus ou moins consciente et cohérente.

Translation:

> A worldview (vision du monde) is precisely this set/totality of aspirations, feelings and ideas that unite the members of a social group (most frequently a social class) and set them against other groups.
> This is doubtlessly an oversimplification, an extrapolation by the historian, but it is the extrapolation of a *real* tendency in the members of a social group who realise/fulfil this class conscience in a more or less conscious and coherent way.

How is this relevant to the study of literature? Goldmann explains (on page 28):

> toute grand oeuvre littéraire ou artistique est l'expression d'une vision du monde. Celle-ci est un phénomène de conscience collective qui atteint son maximum de clarté conceptuelle ou sensible dans la conscience de penseur ou du poète. Ces derniers l'expriment à leur tour dans l'oeuvre qu'étudie l'historien en se servant de l'instrument conceptuel qui est la vision du monde; appliqué au texte, celle-ci lui permet de dégager:
> a) L'essentiel dans les ouvrages qu'il étudie.
> b) La signification des éléments partiels dans l'ensemble de l'oeuvre.
> Ajoutons enfin, que l'historien de la philosophie et de littérature doit étudier non seulement les visions du monde, mais aussi et surtout leurs expressions concrètes.

Translation:

> each great literary or artistic work is the expression of a worldview. This (worldview) is a collective consciousness phenomenon that reaches it highest conceptual or significant clarity in the thinker's or poet's consciousness. The thinker or the poet express this in the work that the historian studies using the conceptual instrument that constitutes "worldview"; applied to the text, this concept allows the historian to uncover:
> a) The essence of the works he studies.
> b) The meaning of the parts in the oeuvre as a whole.
> Let us add that the historian of philosophy or literature must study not only the worldviews but also and above all their concrete expressions.

The term "vision du monde" is a translation of the German term [Weltanschauung], which had been used by philosophers such as Immanuel Kant, G. W. F. Hegel and Wilhelm Dilthey. Goldmann integrates it into a method influenced by the marxist [György Lukács](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gy%C3%B6rgy_Luk%C3%A1cs) (Löwy & Sayre).

It has been pointed out, for example by Peter Zima, that defining the critic's work as uncovering the worldview in a work of literature or an oeuvre has drawbacks. For example, it ignores a work's potential polysemy, and Goldmann's method may therefore by too reductive to approach Avant-garde works that rejected the classical demand for coherence and harmony (Zima, page 46–47).

---

References:

- Goldmann, Lucien: [*Le Dieu caché. Étude sur la vision tragique dans les «Pensées» de Pascal et dans le théâtre de Racine*](http://www.gallimard.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Tel/Le-Dieu-cache). Gallimard, 1956.
- Löwy, Michael; Sayre, Robert: ["Lucien Goldmann et la vision romantique du monde"](https://journals.openedition.org/contextes/8502), *Contextes* 25 (2019).
- Pascal, Blaise: [*Pensées*. Texte établi par Léon Brunschvicg, Hachette, 1925](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es/%C3%89dition_Brunschvicg).
- Pascal, Blaise: [*Pensées de M. Pascal sur la religion et sur quelques autres sujets, qui ont esté trouvées après sa mort parmy ses papiers*](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pens%C3%A9es/%C3%89dition_de_Port-Royal). Guillaume Desprez, 1670, seconde édition (orthographe modernisée).
- Zima, Peter V.: [*Textsoziologie: Eine kritische Einführung*](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783476101907). Springer, 2016.

PS: Goldmann's concept of "vision du monde" predates his genetic structuralism, which is something I was not aware of when I formulated the question.